# rephrasing "seem that"

Tags: vocabulary

**Excerpt from Oxford Dictionary:**

> It would seem that not enough is *being* done to support tiger conversation.

**Revised :**

> Not enough  is seemed to  **being** done to support tiger conversation.

***UPDATED***:
For the sake of parallelism-ing form- I have used the bold part the same as the italic part.

Comment: What is tiger conversation and where do I send my money if I want to support it?

Comment: This is quite impossible. *Seem* cannot be cast in the passive, and *-ing* forms cannot follow the infinitive marker *to*.

Comment: Is this supposed to be _conversation_? Or _conservation_?

Answer (score 1):

Your sentence is not correct.

The following sentence is correct:

> It seems that not enough is being done to support tiger conversation.

You used the wrong word order and as a consequence, the sentence has no meaning.

Comment: Feel free to edit my answer, if you think it's appropriate. Thanks for the review.

Comment: Your suggested sentence makes no sense.

Comment: I felt free to edit it :-)